# Django: get data from fields and insert to 2 tables related to user

Tags: django, forms, django-orm

I have basic html form with 2 fields (email and phone). I have 3 models:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.Charfield()

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = model.EmailField()

class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField()
```

in my **views.py**

```
/imports/

def home(request):
    context = {'users': Person.object.all()}
    return render(request,'app/home.html',context)
```

and my **home.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% for user in users %}
Displaying user's attributes

{% for email in user.email_set.all %}
{{ email }}

{% endfor %}
<form method="POST">
<input type="email">
<input type="label">
<button type="submit">Add data</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

So after clicking button I want to get data from field and add them to 2 tables in my database and this data must be related to clicked user. I know I should use **forms.py** but I try to do this without it. Is there a easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your forms using ModelForm. Then if you want to add, update or delete `phone` or `email`, you could do it from an other view using **formset_factory**. I suggest something like this.

**forms.py**

```
from yourapp.models import Person, Email, Phone
from django.forms impot ModelForm


class EmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.forms import formset_factory


def view_to_update_person_data(request, pk):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk)
    email_formset = model_factory(EmailForm, extra=2)
    for email in person.email_set.all():
        email_formset = email_formset(initial=[{'person': email}]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # you can proceed one formset by one
        if email_formset.is_valid():
            instances = email_formset.save(commit=false)
            for i in instances:
                i.person = person
                i.save()

    ctx = {'email_formset': email_formset,
           'phone_form': phone_form,
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'your/template/html', ctx)
```

See how to use formset in [working with forms page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: no, my user is not authenticated. In db there are users but I dont need to use any authentication, just work on them

Comment: If you need to work on them from a list for example, you just need add a user primary key as argument to your view. With the pk, you get your user and then you can instantiate your forms.

Comment: I don't know if you found a solution. I've edited the solution using formset.